# why is it "Ein Geschenk meiner Mutter" and not "von meiner Mutter"

Tags: word-usage

why is von not after a present from my Mother and is in a present from me ?

Comment: It would probably help if you gave complete sentences for context. Perhaps something like "Das ist ein Geschenk meiner Mutter."

Comment: The body of the question should be understandable without reading the title. Also, try to include all relevant information; for instance, is *ein Geschenk von mir* something you had in mind as a comparison?

Comment: Both is possible. We need more context. Please edit your post.

Comment: I did not vote to close, but I had a hard time parsing your question.

Answer (score 1):

Both are valid ways to express the same meaning.

**Noun + genitive noun:**

> Ein Geschenk meiner Mutter

Literal translation:

> A present of my mother

Correct translation:

> A present from my mother

This use of genitive is higher register than the following variant.

**Noun + "von" + dative noun:**

> Ein Geschenk von meiner Mutter

Literal and correct translation:

> A present from my mother

You can do the same with "ich" instead of "Mutter":

> Ein Geschenk meiner

However, the singular genitive of "ich" is rarely used nowadays and the expression would be extremely old-fashioned. To a modern native speaker it feels wrong. We would use the other variant:

> Ein Geschenk von mir